How to remove and replace USB wireless dongle programmatically
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 (8G) with the Debian Lite OS, Rii Wireless keyboard and mouse.
The keyboard is fine, but the mouse freezes quite often while watching Youtube or video. My solution is to physically unplug the USB dongle and plug it back in again. The mouse unfreezes and continues to work as expected until it inevitably freezes again.
My question: Is there a way to programmatically unplug and replug the dongle, with a script, from the keyboard, saving me the trouble of getting up and moving to the RPi across the room?
Incidentally, when using the ArchLinuxArm 32 bit OS with the same equipment, there is no mouse freezing. Only with the Debian and Raspbian do I have mouse freeze.

Sir Nate's solution worked well. Thanks.

I'm glad the solution worked. You may also want to check the system logs (e.g. dmesg) to see if there are any messages connected to it freezing - possibly you just need to update the driver or something given it works on the Arch.

Yes, you can use usbreset from usbutils. Other options listed here
